# SQL Server : validate XML

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005, validation

I'm using SQL Server 2005 and 2008 and am trying to import a variety different XML files into my db, and occasionally the XML is not valid. Each XML file will differ from the last.

Is there any way to create a function which will return 0 or 1 depending on whether the XML is valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
try
 {
   XDocument xdfile = new XDocument();
   xdfile = XDocument.Load(your_filepath);
 }
 catch (XmlException exception)
 {
     ShowMessage("Invalid");
 }
```

SQL server: refer below links

1. http://www.sqlteam.com/article/xml-validator
2. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/12/02/sql-server-validate-an-xml-document-in-tsql-using-xsd-by-jacob-sebastian/

Comment: Thanks, but i was hoping for a t-sql function. Although it might be that i have to get .net involved at some point!

Comment: Check the links there they might help you

Comment: They mainly want to validate by schema, I have many many different schemas and therefore need this to be dynamic!

Comment: Ended up using the .net approach, so will credit you with the answer.